# upload image to imagefield with djangorestframework using json and test this with CURL

Tags: django, json, curl, imagefield, django-rest-framework

I have made several apis in djangorestframework.
This I could test both with the html form of the api as with curl in commandline.

Now I have an api to a Model with one off the fields an ImageField.

I can't figure out which curl command to use.
Using the syntax I used before fot post actions in json format, it would be:

```
curl -X POST -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u "username:password" --data-binary '{"otherfields":"something", "photo":"/home/michel/test.jpg"}' 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/
```

but in this case the photo will not be saved and left empty (the photo is an optional field)

adding `-T /home/michel/test.jpg`
I get an error message saying 127.0.0.1:800/api/v1/test.jpg does not exist as an url.

In the test html form of djangorestframework, all works fine.

Using the `-F` option, it says I can only do 1 request at a time...
I also removed the datatype from data-binary

Can anybody help me how to make this curl post with both the image and the other data in json in 1 command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a long puzzle, this seems to do the trick:

- put all json arguments in separate `-F` arguments
- only use the header `Accept` (not `Content-Type`)
- And specify the image type
- Use `@` to indicate the local file to upload

  ```
  curl -X POST -S \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -u "username:password" \
    -F "otherfields=something" \
    -F "photo=@/home/michel/test.jpg;type=image/jpg" \
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/
  ```

By the way, I know all of this is on the documentation site of curl, but just missed an example of all those things together since there are a lot of options to try out.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?   `$ curl -X POST -S -H "Accept-Language: en-en" -H 'Accept: application/json' \
-F "name=Avatar" \
-F "username=avatar" \
-F "password=A1234567" \
-F "email=avatar@user.com" \
-F "token=748e14e32ce165d06365d3c9a00cee3f" \
-F "avatar=@/home/moreno/Pictures/avatar004.jpg;type=image/jpg" 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/register/` response 400 `{"username":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."],"name":["This field is required."],"avatar":["No file was submitted."],"email":["This field is required."]}`

Comment: it is missing one of the reuired fields. You need to use -u in front of username, not -F (unless it's also a field in the api, than you need to use both)

Comment: @michel-iamit thanks. I decided to send the images as a base64 field e.g.: `curl -H "Authorization: JWT ey...5U" -d "name=User Name&username=user&email=user@mail.com&password=A1234567" --data-urlencode 'avatar='"$( base64 ~/Pictures/avatar004.jpg)"'' --data-urlencode 'image='"$( base64 ~/Pictures/avatar001.jpg)"'' --data-urlencode 'picture='"$( base64 ~/Pictures/577383.jpg)"'' http://localhost:8000/api/v1//register/`