# django-rest-framework and uploading images

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an image field using [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) how to I handle the uploading of images over the API?

Is there any examples?

**models.py**

```
image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="profiles",
        height_field="height",
        width_field="width",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=True,
        help_text="Profile Picture",
        verbose_name="Profile Picture"
    )
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398696/upload-image-to-imagefield-with-djangorestframework-using-json-and-test-this-wit

Answer (score 2):

Finally I am able to upload image using Django. 
Here is my working code

views.py

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
# parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

# media_type = 'multipart/form-data'
# format = 'jpg'

def post(self, request, format='jpg'):
    up_file = request.FILES['file']
    destination = open('/Users/Username/' + up_file.name, 'wb+')
    for chunk in up_file.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()

    # ...
    # do some stuff with uploaded file
    # ...
    return Response(up_file.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
url(r'^imageUpload', views.FileUploadView.as_view())
```

curl request to upload

```
curl -X POST -S -H -u "admin:password" -F "file=@img.jpg;type=image/jpg" 127.0.0.1:8000/resourceurl/imageUpload
```

Comment: Didn't you face `I/O operation on closed file` ?

Comment: It was my fault, because I used `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` instead of default.

Answer (score 0):

The image field doesn't store the image but rather a link to it. Do you have MEDIA_URL set in settings? eg MEDIA_URL = '/media/' If you're running on localhost you should find the image at localhost/media/profiles/image_name.png